# Select an attribute value with the Expression String Builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgsexpression, composer-manager

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover and this should be very straightforward but I'm unable to solve it.

I'm producing different maps, filtering the features of a layer. In the composer manager, I'm trying to create an automated legend title using the Expression String Builder that includes the value of an attribute of the first feature of that filtered layer. All my attempts with the commands `attribute()` and `get_feature()` or `get_feature_by_id()` have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function for that:

```
array_get( aggregate(layer:='my_layer',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:="my_fieldname"),0)
```

Aggregates all values form field `my_fieldname` of the layer `my_layer` into an array and with
`array_get` you can get the value at position 0

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you. After your answer, another valid option would be array_first(aggregate(layer:='my_layer',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:="my_fieldname"))

Comment: aggregate(layer:='my_layer',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:="my_fieldname")[0]